# Integration gamma and beta: $\int_0^4y^3\sqrt{64-y^3}\,\mathrm dy$

Tags: integration, special-functions, definite-integrals, gamma-function

How can we evaluate the following integral? $$\int_0^4y^3\sqrt{64-y^3}\,\mathrm dy$$
I can't find anything to substitute because all of the trigonometric identities are in square form...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^4 dy \, y^3 (64-y^3)^{1/2} &= \underbrace{2048 \int_0^1 dx \, x^3 (1-x^3)^{1/2}}_{y=4 x} \\ &= \frac{2048}{3} \underbrace{\int_0^1 du \, u^{1/3} \, (1-u)^{1/2}}_{x=u^{1/3}}\\ &= \frac{2048}{3} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{17}{6}\right)} \end{align}$$

Comment: how 2048 came..??

Comment: $4 \cdot 4^3 \cdot \sqrt{64} = 2^8 \cdot 2^3 = 2^{11} = 2048$

Comment: You applied the beta and gamma relation, but beta(m,n) supposed to be x^(m-1)*(1-x)^(n-1) so, how did you put directly 1/3 and 1/2? shouldnt it be something like (1/3-1) type?

Comment: @TamimAdDari: good catch.  Easy to get that mixed up.

Comment: Many thanks Ron, can you help me with another one here please? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426152/hint-of-integration-about-gamma-function

Comment: I would only like to add that $\Gamma(5/6)$ is expressible in terms of $\Gamma(1/3)$: $$\Gamma(5/6)\Gamma^2(1/3)=\frac{2^{4/3}\pi^{3/2}}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: @O.L.: Math.SE is a better place with you here.

Comment: I think there's a typo in the denominator: it should be $\Gamma \left(
17/6\right) $, instead of $\Gamma \left( 11/6\right) $, because $\frac{4}{3}+
\frac{3}{2}=\frac{17}{6}$.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: correct.  Not my day I guess.

Comment: Not your day but a nice answer: (+1).

Comment: how do I find the value of gamma 4/3?

Comment: Well, it is $(1/3) \Gamma(1/3)$, and you can get $\Gamma(1/3)$ here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html . It is not pretty.

Comment: :D and there is no calculation there also :( so there is no practical way to calculate gamma(1/3) by integrating?