# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^4}$.

Tags: integration, special-functions, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Can anyone give me a hint to evaluate this integral?

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^4}$$

I know it will involve the gamma function, but how?

Comment: Consider the change of variables $t=x^4/(1+x^4)$.

Comment: then find the value of dx?

Comment: @O.L. OK, I considered it. And then what?

Comment: @TamimAdDari: Your problem is a special case of one of these [problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).

Comment: @Did Then $1-t=1/(1+x^4)$, $x^4=t/(1-t)$, $\displaystyle dx=\frac{d(x^4)}{4x^3}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)^{3/4}\frac{dt}{(1-t)^2}$
and the integral becomes
$$\frac14\int_0^1t^{-3/4}(1-t)^{-1/4}dt=\frac14 B\left(\frac14,\frac34\right)=\frac{\pi}{4\sin\frac{\pi}{4}}.$$
I thought this is rather obvious.

Comment: @O.L. Thanks for the indication. (You know, everything is "obvious" once you know it, the question is whether "this" was obvious to the OP.)

Comment: @Did I agree. It just seemed to me from the question that the main thing needed by the OP was the change of variables reducing the integral to gamma functions. Of course, there are many alternative methods (if I were asked to compute such integral as fast as possible, I would rather use residues). But since the accepted answer is not the one of **achille hui** and doesn't mention gamma functions at all, it seems that OP doesn't know what he really wants or at least doesn't ask about what he really wants.

Comment: @O.L. To make it short: yes. :-)

Comment: This follows from the more general proof given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34761/6075

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HINT:

Putting $x=\frac1y,dx=-\frac{dy}{y^2}$

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^4}=\int_\infty^0\frac{-dy}{y^2\left(1+\frac1{y^4}\right)}$$
$$=-\int_\infty^0\frac{y^2dy}{1+y^4}=\int_0^\infty\frac{y^2dy}{1+y^4} \text{ as } \int_a^bf(x)dx=-\int_b^af(x)dx$$

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{y^2dy}{1+y^4}=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2dx}{1+x^4}$$

$$\implies 2I=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^4}+\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2dx}{1+x^4}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac1{x^2}+1}{\frac1{x^2}+x^2} dx$$

Now the idea is to express the denominator as a polynomial of $\int \left(\frac1{x^2}+1 \right)dx =x-\frac1x=u\text{(say)}$

$$\text{The denominator =}\frac1{x^2}+x^2=\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+2=u^2+2$$

Now, complete the definite integral with $u$

Comment: @TamimAdDari, so, the limit of $u$ will be $-\infty, +\infty$ and the answer will be  $\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}$

Answer (score 14):

Following is a computation that uses Gamma function:

For any real number $k > 1$, let $I_k$ be the integral:

$$I_k = \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^k}$$

Consider two steps in changing the variable. First by $y = x^k$ and then by $z = \frac{y}{1+y}$. Notice:
$$\frac{1}{1+y} = 1 - z,\quad y = \frac{z}{1-z}\quad\text{ and }\quad dy = \frac{dz}{(1-z)^2}$$
We get:

$$\begin{align}
I_k = & \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1 + y} d y^{\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{1}{k}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+y}y^{\frac{1}{k}-1} dy\\
= & \frac{1}{k}\int_0^1 (1-z) \left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}-1} \frac{dz}{(1-z)^2}
= \frac{1}{k}\int_0^1 z^{\frac{1}{k}-1} (1-z)^{-\frac{1}{k}} dz\\
= & \frac{1}{k} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{k})\Gamma(1 - \frac{1}{k})}{\Gamma(1)}
= \frac{\pi}{k \sin\frac{\pi}{k}}
\end{align}$$

For $k = 4$, we get:

$$I_4 = \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^4} = \frac{\pi}{4\sin \frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 7):

$\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{|z^4+1|} = 0 $ and $\frac{1}{x^4+1}$ is even so you can replace the integral with $\frac{1}{2}2\pi i\sum Res$ considering only the residues in the top half of the complex plane.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $1 + x^4 = (1 + x^2)^2 - (\sqrt{2} x)^2$, so that $1 + x^4 = (1 + \sqrt{2}x + x^2)(1 - \sqrt{2}x + x^2)$. This allows you to use partial fractions in the integral.

If you know contour integration that will also work here.

Comment: good factorization

Comment: I dont know contour integration.. and also cant do the integration you mention here :( because if I part it than a (2+2x^2) becomes divded. same thing

Comment: $\frac{ax + b}{cx^2 + dx + e}$ can always be turned into a log and/or an arctan. The partial fractions section of many textbooks covers this.

Comment: but I cant turn the factor in that form, I am getting this type (ax+b)/(x*(cx^2+dx+e))

Answer (score 4):

let $$I=\int \dfrac{dx}{1+x^4}$$

$$I=\dfrac {1}{2}\int \dfrac {x^2+1-(x^2-1)}{1+x^4} $$

splitting the fraction,

$$I=\dfrac {1}{2} \left(\int \dfrac {x^2+1}{1+x^4} - \int \dfrac {x^2-1}{1+x^4} \right)$$

let $I_1$ =$ \int \frac {x^2+1}{1+x^4}$.

Dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^2$,

$$I_1=  \int \dfrac {1+\dfrac {1}{x^2} }{x^2 +\dfrac {1}{x^2} } $$

put $x-\dfrac{1}{x}=t $ for $I_1$ ( observe that the derivative of $x-\dfrac{1}{x}=t $ is $1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}$)

Let $$I_2 = \int \dfrac {x^2-1}{1+x^4}$$

Dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^2$,

$$I_2 = \int \dfrac {1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\dfrac {1}{x^2}}$$

put $x+\dfrac{1}{x}=t  $ for $I_2$ (observe that the derivative of $x+\dfrac{1}{x}=t  $ is $1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$)

So, $$ I=\dfrac {1}{2} (I_1-I_2) $$

Finally, substitute the limits.

Hope this helps.. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could mess about with integration by substitution methods.

For instance, if you change the expression to this:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{(x^2+1)-(x^2-1)}{x^4+1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{(x^2+1)}{x^4 + 1}-\frac{(x^2-1)}{x^4+1}dx$$
which you can then separate out as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^\infty \frac{(x^2+1)}{x^4+1}dx - \int_0^\infty \frac{(x^2-1)}{x^4+1}dx\right]$$

and then divide the top and bottom in both expressions by $x^2$ to get: 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^\infty \frac{1+ \frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}dx - \int_0^\infty \frac{1- \frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}dx\right]$$

and then you can change some variables. If you take:
$u= x- \frac{1}{x}$ so $du= 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $v= x+\frac{1}{x}$ and $dv = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2}$ 
you can square the functions:

$u^2 = x^2 -2 +\frac{1}{x^2}$ or $u^2 + 2 = x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$

$v^2 = x^2 +2 +\frac{1}{x^2}$ or $v^2-2  = x^2 +\frac{1}{x^2}$

and when you substitute in you end up with

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{u^2+2} - \int_0^\infty \frac{dv}{v^2-2}\right]$$

and from there it should be easier to do, no? I think this was the way I approached it in a class last semester and I saw someone else in the interwebs had done something similar.  :-) so I could be wrong. But I think this should work. Or you could I think rearrange the above substitutions into an integration by parts for each expression. But when I did that it was a long process.

Answer (score 2):

This was one of the questions in my final Infinitesimal Calculus I course (one year long course first undergraduate year)...and thus one has no idea whats' going on and must then try more or less simple things, so partial fractions:

$$x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2\,x+1)\implies$$

$$\frac1{x^4+1}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2-\sqrt2\,x+1}\;,\;A,B,C,D\in\Bbb R\implies$$

$$1=(Ax+B)(x^2-\sqrt2\,x+1)+(Cx+D)(x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1)$$

Comparing respective coefficients of $\,x\,$  and checking what happens with $\,x=0\,$ and etc., we get

$$\frac1{x^4+1}=\frac{x+\sqrt2}{2\sqrt2(x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1)}-\frac{x-\sqrt2}{2\sqrt2(x^2-\sqrt2\,x+1)}$$

and

$$\int\frac{x+\sqrt2}{x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1}dx=\frac12\int\left(\frac{2x+\sqrt2}{x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1}+\frac{\sqrt2-\frac1{\sqrt2}}{x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1}\right)dx=$$

$$=\frac12\log\left(x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1\right)+\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int\frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\frac12}=$$

$$=\frac12\log\left(x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1\right)+\frac1{\sqrt2}\int\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac x{\sqrt2}+\frac12\right)^2}=$$

$$=\frac12\log\left(x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1\right)+\arctan\left(\frac x{\sqrt2}+\frac12\right)$$

Well, take it from here also with *the other* integral, put limits and etc.