# Partial fractions and Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

For the equation:

The indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{x^4+1}$
My question is, without partial fractions to turn this into "integrable" form what can I do?

Is it algabraically possible to manipulate this to fit any of the standard integration rules?  Possibly letting $u=x^2$, giving $\frac{1}{u^2+1}$.

Thanks

Comment: Write the numerator as $\dfrac{x^2+1}2-\dfrac{x^2-1}2$  and use teh concept of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426152/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x4