# Evaluation of $1-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{17}-\dotsb$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

> How can we calculate sum of following infinite  series
>
> $\displaystyle \bullet\; 1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\cdots$
>
> $\displaystyle \bullet\; 1-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{17}-\cdots$

$\textbf{My Try:}$ Let $$S = \int_0^1 (1+x^2-x^4-x^6+x^8+x^{10}+\cdots) \, dx$$

So we get $$S=\int_0^1 \left(1-x^4+x^8-\cdots\right)dx+x^2\int_0^1 (1-x^4+x^8-\cdots)\,dx$$

So we get $$S=\int_0^1 \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \, dx= \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$$ after that we can solve it

Again for second One, Let $$S=\int_0^1 (1-x^6+x^8-x^{14}+x^{16}+\cdots)$$

So we get $$S=\int_0^1 (1+x^8+x^{16}+\cdots) \, dx-\int_0^1 (x^6+x^{14}+
\cdots)\,dx$$

So we get $$S=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^6}{1-x^8}dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{(x^2+1)(x^4+1)}dx$$

Now how can i solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with partial fractions

$$\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{(x^2+1)(x^4+1)} = \frac{A}{x^2+1}+ \frac{B x^2+C}{x^4+1}$$

Thus,

$$A+B=1$$
$$B+C=1$$
$$A+C=1$$

or $A=B=C=1/2$.  Also note that

$$x^4+1 = (x^2+\sqrt{2} x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{2} x+1) $$

so that

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1} = \frac{P}{x^2-\sqrt{2} x+1} + \frac{Q}{x^2+\sqrt{2} x+1}$$

where $P=Q=1/2$.  Thus,

$$\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{(x^2+1)(x^4+1)} = \frac14 \left [2 \frac1{x^2+1} + \frac1{(x-\frac1{\sqrt{2}})^2+\frac12} + \frac1{(x+\frac1{\sqrt{2}})^2+\frac12} \right ]$$

And the integral is

$$\frac12 \frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac14 \sqrt{2} \left [\arctan{(\sqrt{2}-1)}-\arctan{(-1)} \right ] + \frac14 \sqrt{2} \left [\arctan{(\sqrt{2}+1)}-\arctan{(1)} \right ]= \frac{\pi}{8} (\sqrt{2}+1) $$

Answer (score 5):

For the second, you're doing fine. You need to use partial fractions for the integral you've gotten. $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible, but the $x^4 + 1$ may be giving you troubles.

Hint: 
$$x^4 + 1 = 
(x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1)(x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Writing $x^2=y$

$$\dfrac{1+x^2+x^4}{(1+x^2)(1+x^4)}=\dfrac{1+y+y^2}{(1+y)(1+y^2)}$$

Let $$\dfrac{1+y+y^2}{(1+y)(1+y^2)}=\dfrac A{1+y}+\dfrac{By+C}{1+y^2}$$

$$\iff1+y+y^2=A(1+y^2)+(1+y)(By+C)=A+C+y(C+B)+y^2(A+B)$$

Comparing the constants, coefficients $y,y^2$

$$A+B=B+C=C+A=1\iff A=B=C=\dfrac12$$

For $\displaystyle \dfrac{1+x^2}{1+x^4},$  see [Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^4}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426152/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x4)

Can you take it from here?