# Any simple methods of solving this?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question was initially:
$$\int{\frac{1}{x^4+1}dx}$$
By trig substitution I reached the below equation and I'm stuck here:
$$\int\frac{1}{2}{(\cot x)^{1/2}dx}$$
How can I proceed from here?Any simple methods are appreciated.

Comment: I am certain that this question has been asked before on this site...Partial fraction decomposition is a way how to handle this

Comment: I agree with partial fractions, also that is the way [Blackpenredpen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZFQNsy3p1U) solves it.

Comment: That video shows the steps indeed. However, a substitution $x=\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}$ would make the process so much easier. The denominator would then become $t^4+4$ which is $(t^2-2t+2)(t^2+2t+2)$ and partial fraction on this is soooo much easier since there no radicals.

Comment: @Dando18 There's only one solution in that thread (the accepted answer) and it's wrong.

Comment: @studrayght5 perhaps leave a comment on that thread if you believe the accepted answer is incorrect (it seems correct to me)

Comment: @Dando18 It's too old now, so I'm not sure. But I believe that antiderivative is not valid for negative $x$. For example, over $[-1,1]$ integral is obviously greater than 1 but the RHS in that answer gives an answer less than $1$. I think one of the substitutions restricted the domain of validity for the answer.

Comment: @studrayght5 [they appear](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bi9qhgfto6) to only differ by a constant ($c = 0.021392...$).

Comment: @Dando18 I'm not sure what you mean 'only differ by..." since the definite integrals shouldn't be differing by constants, but that particular constant is due to the calculator. They are actually equal on that interval (and the two entries/examples are the same since the function is even, and also agree nicely with the substitution $t = x-1/x$). Try any interval $[a,b]$ s.t. $a < 0 < b$ and see what happens.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426152/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
x^4 + 1 = \Big( x^4 + 2x^2 + 1\Big) - 2x^2 = {} & \Big( x^2+1\Big)^2 - \Big(x\sqrt2\Big)^2 \\
& \qquad \text{ This } \uparrow \text{ is a difference of two squares} \\
& \qquad \text{and can be factored accordingly.} \\[10pt]
= {} & (x^2 + 1 -x\sqrt 2\,)(x^2+1 + x\sqrt 2\,)
\end{align}

Each of these two quadratic factors is irreducible unless you bring in imaginary numbers, and there are various reasons for not doing that on this occasion. You can tell it's irreducible by looking at the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ where $a=1, b = \pm\sqrt 2, c=1,$ and observing that this discriminant is negative.

Then use partial fractions. You'll see something like this:
$$
\int\frac{ax+b}{x^2 + 1 - x\sqrt 2} \, dx\quad \text{ plus another similar integral, and you need to find $a$ and $b$.}
$$
Letting $u = x^2 +1-x\sqrt 2,$ you get $du = (2x - \sqrt 2\,)\,dx,$ and so
$$
(ax+b)\,dx = \frac a 2 \left( 2x + \frac{2b} a \right) \, dx = \underbrace{\frac a 2 (2x - \sqrt2 \,)\,dx}{} + \left( b + \frac{a\sqrt2} 2  \right) \,dx
$$
For the term over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}},$ just use the substitution.

For the other term, you'll have
\begin{align}
& \overbrace{\int \frac k {x^2 + 1 - x\sqrt 2} \, dx = \int \frac k {\left( 
x^2 - x\sqrt 2 + \frac 1 2 \right) + \frac 1 2} \, dx }^\text{completing the square} \\[12pt]
= {} & \int \frac k {\left( x - \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \right)^2 + \frac 1 2} \,dx = \int \frac{2k}{ \left( x\sqrt 2 - 1 \right)^2 + 1 } \, dx = \int \frac{2k}{w^2 + 1} \,\, \frac{dw}{\sqrt 2} = \cdots
\end{align}
and then use the fact that $\displaystyle \int \frac{dw}{w^2+1} = \arctan w + C.$

Comment: this problem is as old as time. i see it asked countless of times.

Comment: The first time I ever saw this (long before m.s.e. existed, of course), my immediate inclination was to write $x^4+1=0$ and then $x^4=-1,$ so $x^2=\pm i,$ and then if $x^2=i$ then $x=\pm(1+i)/\sqrt 2,$ and if $x^2 =-i$ then $x = \pm(1-i)/\sqrt 2.$ Then you have $$\left(x - \frac{1+i}{\sqrt2} \right) \left(x - \frac{1-i}{\sqrt 2}\right) = x^2 - x\sqrt 2 + 1,$$ etc. But most students aren't taught how to work with complex numbers in the same way that I was. It was years before I realized it was possible to define multiplication of  complex numbers without talking about adding "arguments," etc.

Comment: Few students who've had a bare introduction to complex numbers know how to show that if $x^2 = i$ then $x = \pm \dfrac{1+i} {\sqrt 2}.$ How to do that is neglected in conventional courses of study. $\qquad$