# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(x-\sqrt{2})^4}{\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)}\int_{0}^x \frac{t^2}{t^4+1}dt$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Kindly solve the following limit.
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(x-\sqrt{2})^4}{\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)}\int_{0}^x
>  \frac{t^2}{t^4+1}dt$$

It's a $0/0$ form, so I thought of applying L'hospital rule but things got worse.

I can find no simplification. Hints please. I think we need to break that integral part though.

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax. It is very hard to understand what you have written.

Comment: How to use that. im new.

Comment: I've added a mathematical expression. Kindly have a look at it modify it if you think it is incorrect.

Comment: yeah its fine. Thanks.

Comment: Proper usage: "Solve an equation." "Solve a problem." "Calculate a limit." "Find a limit."

Comment: You can find really **no** simplification? What is the limit of $\cos x$ when $x\to 0$? What is the limit of $x-\sqrt 2$ when $x \to 0$?

Comment: I meant if we blindly apply lhospital's rule

Comment: Never apply L'Hospital's Rule blindly. It is always better to manipulate the expression in a form which makes application of L'Hospital's Rule easy and useful.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426152/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x4

Comment: @labbhattacharjee idk what a gamma function is

Comment: @user354545, Could not follow u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(x-\sqrt{2})^4}{\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)}\int_{0}^x
 \frac{t^2}{t^4+1}dt =\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(x-\sqrt2)^4x^3}{\cos^2x \sin^3(x)}\right)\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^3}\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{t^4+1}\,dt\right)\end{align}

Evaluate the two limit on the right separately, use L'hopital rule on one of them.

Comment: Alternatively the limit in last parentheses involving integral can be evaluated by the use of Squeeze Theorem. +1

Comment: (+1) I didn't see this for some reason when I posted my hint.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(x-\sqrt{2})^4}{\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)}\int_{0}^x
 \frac{t^2}{t^4+1}dt &= \left(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(x-\sqrt{2})^4}{\cos^2(x)}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^x
 \frac{t^2}{t^4+1}dt}{\sin^3(x)}\right) \\
&= 4\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{3(x^4+1)\sin^2(x)\cos(x)} \\
&= \frac{4}{3}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}
\end{aligned}$$
where we are just pulling terms out of the product that can be evaluated using $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)/g(x)=f(x_0)/g(x_0)$ and applying L'Hospital's rule once to get rid of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

[Not a complete solution but too long to be a comment.]

What troubles you when applying L'Hopital rule directly to 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(x-\sqrt{2})^4}{\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)}\int_{0}^x
 \frac{t^2}{t^4+1}dt
$$
is that there are some "noise functions" there making the derivatives complicated. But you could separate those parts out. Remember that one has the product rule
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)
$$
when both $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exist. One possible choice is to find $g(x)f(x)$ so that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)\neq 0
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)
$$
could be calculated by L'Hopital rule with less complicated derivative-calculations.