# How to integrate $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{1+x^4}dx$.

I am finding it very difficult to evaluate this integral. I do not know any standard formula for this integral. I cannot think of a suitable substitution. I tried to evaluate the integral by partial fractions but it become a bit messy and integration by parts does not result in a simpler integral. How can you evaluate this integral without using partial fractions?

Comment: Try using u = x^2 and the differentiation for tan inverse x

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426152/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x4

Comment: @BrandonLoi What you suggest won't work, because the integrand becomes, bar the mandatory considerations of sign, $\int^{x^2} \frac{1}{2(1+u^2)\sqrt u}\,du$

Comment: To all users. [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E4%2B1%7D%5C%20%24&p=1) is often better at finding duplicates than the on-site search engine (or Google) when it is essential to include a TeX-snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that$$\frac1{x^4+1}=\frac1{x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2}=\frac1{\left(x^2+\sqrt2x+1\right)\left(x^2-\sqrt2x+1\right)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $1+x^4=(1+\sqrt2x +x^2)(1-\sqrt2x +x^2)$.